# Different result with temp table versus CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have a table FederalReserveHolidays. He wanted to grab the dynamically last day of a recordset. He sent me this

```
DECLARE 
    @dt DATE = '2020-05-25'
   ,@numDays INT = 3
   ,@sameDayDays INT = 1;

SELECT Date = MAX(d.Date)
  FROM (
        SELECT TOP (@sameDayDays+1) Row = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date)
              ,Date
          FROM dbo.FederalReserveHolidays
         WHERE IsBusinessDay = 1
           AND Date >= @dt
  ) d
```

The inner query has result of 2020-05-27 and 2020-05-26 (not my table, I would not have chosen that date structure, not part of the question). However, that outer query returns 2099-12-31, the max date in the table. I get the same thing with a CTE:

```
;with cte AS
(
SELECT TOP (@sameDayDays+1) Row = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date)
        ,Date
FROM dbo.FederalReserveHolidays
WHERE IsBusinessDay = 1
AND Date >= @dt
)

SELECT MAX(date) FROM cte
```

but it returns the expected 2020-05-27 if I use a temp table

```
SELECT TOP (@sameDayDays+1) Row = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date)
        ,Date
into #temp
FROM dbo.FederalReserveHolidays
WHERE IsBusinessDay = 1
AND Date >= @dt

SELECT MAX(date) FROM #temp
```

So, why do the CTE and the inner query not provide an upper end? If I just select everything from the CTE I get exactly what I expect.

Comment: TOP n without order by can give you any n rows. It is execution plan dependent. Put an order by if you want a deterministic result. In the first 2 cases you never reference the row column so it gets optimised out giving no reason to sort the rows but even with it in no result is guaranteed without an order by at the end of the query containing the top

Comment: You have two core (but common) misconceptions here. Firstly as already mentioned, without an `ORDER BY`, there's no guarantee of the order that rows are returned, so your `TOP` is just picking the top x rows of an indeterminately ordered set of rows. Secondly, date data stored in the _correct_ data type (i.e. `date` or `datetime`) has no inherent format. The client tool decides how it is formatted.

Comment: how could I have missed the missing order by! Thank you, that was, of course, the issue. I don't see how to mark the comment as the answer, I suppose I can't